# Find version of a module

Tags: go, go-modules, gomock

We are working with Go modules. I want in a CLI to get the specific version of a module. Is it possible?

If you are curious, the reason is that I want to add the following `generate` command:

```
//go:generate go run github.com/golang/mock/mockgen -source="$GOPATH/pkg/mod/mymodules.com/mymodule@${VERSION}/module.go" -destination=module_mock.go
```

So I need to somehow get the version

Comment: Why not just parsing the `go.mod` file?

Comment: It's possible, but it's quite difficult to do it as part of the go:generate. If I will hard-code it, every time I will update the module, the command will break, so I prefer to get the version dynamically

Comment: I don't understand - you can dynamically parse `go.mod` right?

Comment: `go list -m -u all` piped to `grep` would do it, but I'd try to avoid generating mocks of a third-party package. Rather, write an interface for it in your own project, and mock that.

Comment: This might not get you what you want, but if you run `go mod vendor`, then all module packages will be available in the local directory without versions. That will make `-source="vendor/mymodules.com/mymodule/module.go"` work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Basics**:

`go list -m all` — View final versions that will be used in a build for all direct and indirect dependencies

`go list -u -m all` — View available minor and patch upgrades for all direct and indirect dependencies

**Example**:

To get the version of a specific module, let's say `golang.org/x/text`

```
go list -m all | grep golang.org/x/text | awk '{print $2}'
```

or

```
go list -u -m all | grep golang.org/x/text | awk '{print $2}'
```

**So, the general way**:

```
go list -u -m all | grep <module-name> | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: You can omit the grep and awk like such: `go list -m -f '{{ .Version }}' moduleImport`

Answer (score 20):

Late but worth to mention, if you want to check the all available versions of a specific module:

`go list -m -versions <module_name>`

Like:

`go list -m -versions github.com/user/module-name`

Comment: tried it and got a `go: can't determine available versions using the vendor directory`

Answer (score -2):

This command will get the version of `go` that's used in a project.

`[$]> grep -m 1 go go.mod | cut -d\  -f2`

That'll output a version like `1.18`.